# Do I need a visa for a layover in Germany if I have a type C Schengen visa for Spain?

Tags: germany, transit-visas, spain, munich

So I'm gonna travel to Spain next Monday from Japan and I'm a Philippine passport holder but residence here in Japan. I got my type C schengen visa single entry from the Spanish embassy.

My itinerary has a 5 hour layover in Munich, Germany and I need to pick up my luggage and re check in again, do I still need a visa in germany?

Answer (score 3):

> do i still need a visa in Germany?

No, your visa is good for this itinerary. When you land in Germany your immigration will be processed and then the onward flight will be domestic (within Schengen Area).

Comment: Even my port of entry is Jerez de la frontera Spain?and just having a layover in munich germany and gonna pick up my luggage and check it in again in munich?

Comment: Yes, it is just fine. You will clear immigration wherever you first reach the Schengen zone. In this case when you are transiting in Germany your visa will be stamped and you then can  go on to your final destination Spain.